# java compare to different options

Tags: java, class, compare

I have implemented compareTo to allow me to compare my class' based on some criteria and it is working fine.

However, at some point I want to compare the class' on one thing and at another point in the code I want to compare the class based on another thing.

Is it possible to have two different implementations of compareTo and using one at some point and one at another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the mechanism to do this is to implement one or more [Comparators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use the appropriate one as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Class is "Comparable" you can use the compareTo, you can't - however - create more then one implementation of that function to be used at different points in the same Class (you have one function to override, and you can't do that twice).

You can, however, take a look at the [Comparator Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html); and implementation of that interface can allow you to implement and use a different compareTo for your object.

Answer (score 0):

We achieved something similar by writing a utility comparator for our class - something like this:

```
public class FooComparator implements Comparator<Foo> {

    public static String COMPARE_FIELD1 = "COMPARE_FIELD1";
    public static String COMPARE_FIELD2 = "COMPARE_FIELD2";
    public static String COMPARE_FIELD3 = "COMPARE_FIELD3"; 
    private String compareBy = COMPARE_FIELD1;
    private boolean reverse = true;

    public FooComparator(){}

    public FooComparator(String sort){
        compareBy = sort;
    }

    public void reverse() {
        if(reverse) {reverse = false;
        } else {reverse = true;}
    }

    public void field1Sort() {compareBy = COMPARE_FIELD1;}
    public void field2Sort() {compareBy = COMPARE_FIELD2;}
    public void field3Sort() {compareBy = COMPARE_FIELD3;}

    public int compare(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
        if(compareBy.equals(COMPARE_FIELD2)) {
            return compareByField2(foo1, foo2);
        } else if(compareBy.equals(COMPARE_FIELD3)) {
            return compareByField3(foo1, foo2);
        } 
        return compareByField1(foo1, foo2);
    }

    private int compareByField1(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {       
        if(reverse) {return foo1.getField1().compareTo(foo2.getField1());}
        return foo1.getField1().compareTo(foo2.getField1());        
    }

    private int compareByField2(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {       
        if(reverse) {return foo1.getField2().compareTo(foo2.getField2());}
        return foo1.getField2().compareTo(foo2.getField2());        
    }

    private int compareByField3(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {       
        if(reverse) {return foo1.getField3().compareTo(foo2.getField3());}
        return foo1.getField3().compareTo(foo2.getField3());        
    }   
}
```

We then can use it like this:

```
List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
FooComparator comparator = new FooComparator(FooComparator.COMPARE_FIELD1);     
Collections.sort(foos, comparator);
```